# Environmental Error occurs while installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-3.7

When installing Tensorflow it said I was missing a file but i dont know how to fix it and or get that file

I have tried re-downloading python but I am still missing the file

```
pip install Tensorflow
```

What I want is for the installation to complete.
Here is the error message:

> C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\linear_optimizer\python\utils\__pycache__\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc'

Comment: Is that the complete error message? It's just a path to a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical Windows problem with long file paths. Disable the `MAX_PATH` limitation; the instruction for that can e.g. be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation):

> #### 3.1.2. Removing the MAX_PATH Limitation
>
> Windows historically has limited path lengths to 260 characters. This meant that paths longer than this would not resolve and errors would result.
>
> In the latest versions of Windows, this limitation can be expanded to approximately 32,000 characters. Your administrator will need to activate the “Enable Win32 long paths” group policy, or set the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled` to `1`.

After that, reboot and retry the installation.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Tensorflow it said I was missing a file but i don't know how to fix it and or get that file.

Create a environment using anaconda.

This Problem can be solved by execute the Below commands:

```
conda update anaconda
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
conda install --force html5lib
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
conda install jupyter
```

Refer this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials

Finally you can able to install Tensorflow.

I hope it will help you.