# Tensorflow installation problem on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on a Win 10 machine.

I installed Python (3.7) successfully and then tried to followed the installation instructions on tensorflow.org.

When executing

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I get the following error message:

> **ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\_vendor\tensorflow_serving\sources\storage_path\__pycache__\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-37.pyc'**

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Try to run the command line with administrator privileges.

Comment: Opened CMD with administrator privileges. Didn't help.

Comment: Do you have anaconda installed in your system

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727782/environmental-error-occurs-while-installing-tensorflow) answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the Max_path limitation has not removed. You can read information about it from  3.1.2 on https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html. 
I meet the same trouble as you did and I solve it by setting the registry value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled to 1. You can do it by Win+R, and type regedit and you can change the setting above.  Hope my answer works for you.