# Error in installation of 'tensorflow' library in pycharm version 2020.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have python version 3.8 with pip 20.1.1 version 
i am installing tensorflow library for python to work in pycharm 2020.1 
But i am getting this error after it is installed fully:

[image: Image of Error while installing library]

Please help me in resolving my error
I am using this command to install:

```
Python -m pip install tensorflow
```

Error is :

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Nabia\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\canned\\linear_optimizer\\python\\utils\\__pycache__\\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-38.pyc'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this tread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388330/tensorflow-installation-problem-on-windows-10?rq=1). It's a common problem for windows os with long file paths, disable the MAX_PATH limitation.

Comment: Thank you! it got installed by following those steps