# Can't download tensorflow due to EnvironmentError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow. I am using this command:

```
python3.7 -m pip install tensorflow
```

But every time I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\gjohn\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

It gets to the part where it says this:

```
Running setup.py install for termcolor ... done
Running setup.py install for wrapt ... done
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? In File Explorer, I looked up the directory. It said it didn't exist. But if you only use one / instead of two(//), it finds it. Any way I can have it use the correct directory?

Comment: Make sure you are using Python 64-bit edition and you are running your command prompt as administrator/superuser.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727782/environmental-error-occurs-while-installing-tensorflow

Comment: And this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24835

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to path length limits on Windows.

```
Hit the Windows key, type gpedit.msc and press Enter.
Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative 
Templates >    System > Filesystem.
Double click the Enable Win32 long paths option and enable it.
```

reference : [longpathenable](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing)